# Change password Bitnami CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, bitnami

This is my first time using Cloud to host a CouchDB. When CouchDB installing locally on Windows, it is really easy to use. But I just couldn't figure out how to use CouchDB on Cloud (Bitnami)..

I tried to change my password folloing this [link](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/#how-to-change-the-couchdb-admin-password). At the second step of

> Edit your /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/local.ini configuration file,
>   editing the respective admin password to what you want

I got stuck. Where can I find the "/opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/local.ini"??

Answer (score 2):

You need to log in your server via SSH and then, using the console, access to the file `/opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/local.ini` using a Text Editor such as VIM:

`sudo vim /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/local.ini`

In order to log into your server via SSH, you can follow the guide below:
[How To Connect to the Server](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh)